# Error: The specified Root Directory "main" does not exist

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am getting this error while deploying my personal portfolio website.

It happened after i created SECURITY.md file,

Before that my website was successfully deployed.

[image: Here's the error message Screenshot.]

i have tried searching the problem, did'nt get the solution.